# Unity Custom Editor Handles DrawWireArc for 2D view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a `Handles.DrawWireArc` to display in the correct orientation when using the 2D view. So the wirearc and the lines are facing the camera.

Through the magic of Photoshop, this is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

But now mater what I put in the `normal` parameter of the DrawWireArc, I can't get it to rotate on the Y so that it faces the camera.

This is what I end up with:

[image]

When viewed in 3D

[image]

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(FieldOfView))]
public class FieldOfViewEditor : Editor
{
    private FieldOfView _fieldOfView;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _fieldOfView = (FieldOfView) target;
    }

    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        Handles.color = Color.white;
        Handles.DrawWireArc(_fieldOfView.transform.position, Vector3.left, Vector3.forward, 360, _fieldOfView.viewRadius);

        Vector3 viewAngleA = DirFromAngle(_fieldOfView.transform, -_fieldOfView.viewAngle / 2, false);
        Vector3 viewAngleB = DirFromAngle(_fieldOfView.transform, _fieldOfView.viewAngle / 2, false);

        Handles.DrawLine(_fieldOfView.transform.position, _fieldOfView.transform.position + viewAngleA * _fieldOfView.viewRadius);
        Handles.DrawLine(_fieldOfView.transform.position, _fieldOfView.transform.position + viewAngleB * _fieldOfView.viewRadius);

        Handles.color = Color.red;
        foreach (Transform visibleTarget in _fieldOfView.visibleTargets)
        {
            Handles.DrawLine(_fieldOfView.transform.position, visibleTarget.position);
        }

    }

    public Vector3 DirFromAngle(Transform _transform, float angleInDegrees, bool angleIsGlobal)
    {
        if (!angleIsGlobal)
            angleInDegrees += _transform.eulerAngles.y;

        return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0, Mathf.Cos(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem:

You want the **normal** to be `Vector3.forward` and the **from** be `Vector3.right`. So switch them to

```
Handles.DrawWireArc(_fieldOfView.transform.position, Vector3.forward, Vector3.right, 360, _fieldOfView.viewRadius);
```

Then for the second (the lines)

Since you want to use the Z axis you have to switch Y and Z in your angle vector and invert the Cos

```
if (!angleIsGlobal)
    // Use Z rotation here as well
    angleInDegrees += _transform.eulerAngles.z;

return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), -Mathf.Cos(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0);
```

---

Now with e.g.

```
public float viewAngle = 60;
public float viewRadius = 1;
```

it looks like

[image]

---

Note that all of this currently only works if the camera is aligned with the world coordinate axis.

As soon as the camera shall be able to be rotated you would probably use `camera.tranform.forward, camera.transform.right` for the `DrawWireArc`.

Then you will have to take the camera orientation also into account for the angles and line drawings.

Comment: This is the solution. However, thoughts on why the lines do not rotate with the object?

Comment: Try to additionally in the `DirFromAngle` method switch the `eulerAngles.y` to a `z`!

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you!